# How would YOU design the sound of fingernails on a floor?

Tags: sound-design, foley, sound-effects-recording, creature

Specifically, the sound of an animal/deranged human/creature of some sort skittering and clattering around on a stone floor?

My application is for a large weighty creature, but your answers can address small, medium or large entities.

Go!

Comment: Sorry for the unproductive comment - but this is fascinating to a 'music engineer' who's never done foley ever. Looking forward to the answers ... & a *most welcome* change from our recent plethora of "How do I make this bass sound in VST?", "can I plug my android into xyz?", "How do I remove the vocals from an mp3?"  & "Mi HDMI no werky" that we've been plagued with recently. ;)

Comment: I most certainly second that.

Comment: @ChristianvanCaine, by upvoting and starring favorite questions (and answers), you can help the moderators see that topics like this are favored by the users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sound of dog I actually normally just use a kind of heavy-duty gloves I've epoxy-glued paper-clips on. I was gonna try other things as well when it was still just gaffed on, like pieces of horn and different types of wood, but truth be told I found this configuration to be absolutely spot-on for what I needed instantly!

For the sense of weight, I've used different stuff depending on the character it's intended for, but low-passed piezo-disc through a Radial PZDI gaffed to a sand punching-bag, or the same piezo on the wooden floor (it resonates, but the lowpass erases the feeling of wood when using it for other surfaces), which I bashed from different distances for different results with a canvas bag filled with sand, turned out to be the bee's knees for several kinds of creatures, like a werewolf-esque monster, and huge dogs. I've also used said sand-bag to slam into the floor to simulate heavy steps, but do mind the back, these things wight like a small mountain...

Comment: LOVE the bits of horn idea! That had not occurred to me. And the sand bag via contact mic is a great way to add weight, for sure. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: De nada! I actually just bought my whole contact-mic setup this spring! Absolutely love it, there is a whole world out there hidden in the illusions of the apparent, just waiting for people like us to find and enjoy!